# Constructor for Magento Controller

Tags: magento2, module, magento-1, controllers

I need constructor or init function that can be run for my custom module. I need to call it every time when request made to my module's controller in magento.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add following function to use your logic to your custom module's controller:

```
   protected function _construct()
    {
        // your logic of construct
    }
```

I hope this will help

Answer (score 4):

Magento already has this. You can use `_construct` if you want your logic when the controller is instantiated or you can use `preDispatch` that is called when an action is called.
Just make sure that your controller extends `Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action` if it's a frontend controller or `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action` if it's an admin controller.

Answer (score 0):

Kamesh Jungi's answer is correct for both Magento 1 and Magento 2, but it is vitally important to be careful to use the Magento single-underscore pseudo constructor:

```
protected function _construct() // Note SINGLE underscore
{
    // Your fine code
}
```

The framework invokes this pseudo-constructor, and it **does not override the native PHP constructors** in base classes.

You must also ensure that your Controller class extends the Magento Controller. Marius' answer is applicable to Magento 1 (e.g. `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action` for admin controllers), for Magento 2 it would be `Magento\Backend\App\Action`.